# Cassandra Data Modelling - Identifying Best Row Key

Tags: cassandra

I have a platform where various apps put notes, the notes are identified by `note_id` and apps are identified by `app_key`, both `note_id` and `app_key` are unique, and all my queries are confined to single app key only, I won't need to query for notes across multiple apps.

Now I have to choose a primary key.

If I choose only `app_key` as **partition key** and `note_id` as **clustering key**, there will be ***wide rows***. That is all the notes of a single app will be grouped against `app_key` in a single partition.

**So:**

1. Find all `notes` of an `app` will be efficient (Single partition seek).
2. Find one `note` of an `app` will be efficient.
3. Delete all `notes` of an `app` will be efficient.
4. Delete one `note` of an `app` is efficient.

However there is no guarantee **how wide** a row will be, i.e. no limit on number of `notes` a single `app` can have. The data distribution will be uneven. All `notes` of an `app` will be in a **single partition**, so an `app` having huge number of `notes` will create a huge partition resulting in **hotspots**.

Now lets check option B, **partion key** will be both `app_key` and `note_key`

In this case partition count for an `app` will depend on  the number of `notes` it will have

1. Find all `notes` of an `app` (Not possible)
2. Find one `note` of an `app` (Efficient assuming seeking to a partition is fast)
3. Delete all `notes` of an `app` (Not possible)
4. Delete a single `note` is fast (Assuming the same as above)

---

**So my questions are:**

- What is the correct balance here?
- Am I missing any concepts?
- Do the hotspots really matter?
- As in the 2nd option an entire query is not possible, are there any alternatives to model this?

Comment: Please note that for composite partition key (option B) you have to restrict values for all the columns forming the partition key (both `app_key` and `note_id`). In case you need to find all notes of an app how could be the query?

Comment: good point, I missed that, editing

Comment: If finding all notes of a single app is one of your requirements then I see that option B is not valid at all.
For option A, I see that you need to run a performance test with real data to see the severity of hotspots that could be formed and what hardware specifications (i.e. number of machines and machines specs) will be needed for your solution to scale.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be you divide you partition in time based bucket (eg: daily/weekly/monthly/yearly) based on through put so that you don't suffer from wide row partition..

For example in case of daily partition your partition key will be (app-key, insert_day)..here insert_day is date eg 8-8-2018-00:00:00:000 ....

Now when it comes to read all notes by app-key you need to iterate from current day till days when you no more find data.. same goes with delete.. chose bucket so that it reduces number of iterations.

The note-id (clustering key) you can take it of type time-uuid (which will be generated from insert-date)..now when it comes to select by note-id and appkey.. you can calculate the required insert-day from node-id value (ie, note-id -> insert-date ->insert-day)

Comment: that could be one way, while I am still trying to solve this, do you think secondary indices or materialized view could enable other queries in option B ?

Comment: Better we avoid secondary index due to performance issues although there are some specific case where it can work but not sure how you will plan to use SI in this case..As far as MV is concerned  whether it is production ready or not is a point of discussion,